# Opening HTML window with target=“myFrame” -- display it

Tags: jquery

Assume on a page 'main' a first call of

> ```
> window.open('info.html','myFrame');
> ```

will open new page/tab and the focus is changed to it.

Now the idea is to reuse that page with the target "myFrame", think about info/docu pages called form a menu on the 'main' page.

So, going back to the 'main' page and repeat the call with another page like 'info1.html' will load that 'info1.html' to page/tab with the 'myFrame' target, but it will not change to it .. the focus remains on 'main'. So maybe the user will be confused, search the requested info1.

This all is about a HTML project using jQuery, so maybe there is a way to pass the focus to the target page/tab -- always.

How to get that done?

Comment: Have you tried to close the `myFrame` tab before recalling window open? `if(myFrame) myFrame.close(); myFrame = window.open('info1.html','myFrame');`  ?

Comment: OK, that way it works! Thanks.

The only point, the page/tab is removed and reopened which make some unusable display .. but better then before ;)